# At what point does a field become a field?

Tags: publications

Perhaps I can contextualize the question better, but I’m curious if there’s a kind of incubation trajectory by which new academic fields emerge.

In contemporary scholastic publishing, is there some graded sequence of steps, like, first, a paper is published in some existing, established field’s journal; next, if more papers are published citing that paper, a conference may be organized, recognizing the topic in its own right; and then? Do professors decide to found a journal, perhaps? And then, somewhere, someone designs the first textbook, and/or degree, in the topic?

At each of these stages, what kind of academic regulation is there, or structure, to determine if something is robust enough to attain that standing?

Thank you.

Comment: Long ago I read an analysis of cross-reference patterns in research papers.  (I think it was by Web of Science.) That concluded that when the number of (independent) authors publishing on a subject exceeds roughly 100, then that subject starts behaving like a separate field.

Comment: When there are cows out standing in it?

Comment: When every element other than the additive identity has a multiplicative inverse?

Comment: @XanderHenderson What's the multiplicative inverse of a cow?

Comment: @avid $(cow)^{-1} = w^{-1}o^{-1}c^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

The typical trajectory of a field is that first people publish their work at the fringes of existing journals, then hold workshops with like-minded people, then perhaps found a journal or two that are dedicated to publishing articles in this area, and finally there are full-fledged conferences.

In my own particle field, Computational Science and Engineering (CS&E), people originally published in journals such as the SIAM Journal on Numerical Analysis, originally founded in 1964, and in particular in engineering-oriented journals. Sometime in the 1980 people started to think of CS&E as a separate direction, there were workshops, and journals such as the SIAM Journal on Scientific Computing (originally founded in 1980) started to gain traction even though they were relatively small until around 2000. The first SIAM Conference on Computational Science and Engineering I went to was in 2003, when it had ~300 people. (I believe the first one in the series was held in 2001.) The last one I went to, in 2023, had about 2000 people.

I think that this kind of trajectory is pretty typical for fields.

Answer (score 0):

A field can obviously be pretty large, or not. It's essentially when a class of people within one field (usually) start working on a topic and it spreads elsewhere. For example, i work in econometrics. One of my main areas of interest is machine learning and synthetic control designs for causal inference. Putting applied pieces aside, the machine learning developments to SC are at this point their own field. You originally had economists like Susan Athey and her husband, Guido Imbens, discuss it as the (now often quoted) "most important method in the last 15 [now 20] years".

Now, people from Columbia, to MIT, to places in China, Stanford, and elsewhere, they're all clamoring to make developments on the method. To be a little less specific, it becomes a proper field, to me, when you could legitimately write a book or 2 on the subject. After articles stop doing a topic justice, after it goes beyond one or three papers, then you can call it a field that people do real work in. But this is just my view, there's no hard and fast standard that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another criterion.

When a topic stops depending on individual people or tight-knit clusters working on it to make progress, I would call it a field. In other words, if you can take main player/clusters out and there are still people working on it, it becomes a field.

I have seen an exotic research question ramp up into a community research question in the matter of very few years. It's a field now. It's not a huge community, but it does not depend on specific clusters of people anymore to survive.